# Isolation Transformer 115V Input, Is there a way to use it on 230V input?

Tags: transformer

I bought an Isolation Transformation Station with 115V, only to realize later that it should be 230V Input. Is there a way to convert it to 230V input with 230V output, apart from changing the fuse from 115V to 230V?

Comment: You bought yourself a new boat anchor.

Comment: Sell the transformer, buy the correct voltage one.

Comment: Or buy another one and run the two in series.

Answer (score 3):

> Isolation Transformer 115V Input, Is there a way to use it on 230V input?

No. Each transformer core requires a certain number of turns per volt to avoid saturation. A 230 V transformer will require twice as many turns on the primary as a 115 V transformer.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to convert it to 230V input with 230V output, apart
> from changing the fuse from 115V to 230V?*

Absolutely not without a full rewind of the copper.

Answer (score -1):

There were probably design tradeoffs made to make the transformer smaller, lighter, and cheaper...including such things as size/weight reductions from using insulated wire or other insulators rated for only 115V and specifying the winding diameter for the rated current.  They'll probably be OK at 125V, but 230V, a doubling of the rated voltage (and quadrupling of the power through the same load) is a lot to ask.  You could try it in the lab and see if you get lucky, but even if immediate destruction is avoided, you're still stressing the system beyond its rated limits every moment you use it.

Comment: Doubling the rated voltage on a transformer does not result in a doubling of the current and quadrupling of the power. The current rises by an order or two of magnitude, for a short while, before ideally the fuse or breaker opens.

Comment: I was talking about same load, steady state, and left the fuse blowing for an exercise by the student.